# Linking my gallery with select file button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a gallery using JavaScript and CSS and I've also got some HTML code for a select file button but I'm unsure how I can link the both of them together so that when a user selects a picture file from their computer it shows up on the gallery. Also I think that it would be useful if you see my code so far. So here is the JaavaScript code:

```
$(".scrollable").scrollable();

$(".items img").click(function() {
    // see if same thumb is being clicked
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { return; }

    var url = $(this).attr("src").replace("_t", "");

    // get handle to element that wraps the image and make it semi-transparent
    var wrap = $("#image_wrap").fadeTo("medium", 0.5);

    var img = new Image();


    // call this function after it's loaded
    img.onload = function() {

        // make wrapper fully visible
        wrap.fadeTo("fast", 1);

        wrap.find("img").attr("src", url);

    };


    img.src = url;

    // activate item
    $(".items img").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

// when page loads simulate a "click" on the first image
}).filter(":first").click();
var url = $(this).attr("alt");
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/* styling for the image wrapper  */
#image_wrap {
    /* dimensions */
    width:700px;
    padding:15px 0;

    /* centered */
    text-align:center;

    /* some "skinning" */
    background-color:#8DAAFF;
    border:2px solid  #8DAAFF;
    outline:1px solid #8DAAFF;
    -moz-ouline-radius:4px;
}
```

And finally here is the code for the select file button:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Select File:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: There are ways to access the image data without uploading, but they are limited to rather new browsers. If you want to reach a broad mass of users, it is best that you implement an upload handler on the server side. You could use PHP to do that.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how I could start an upload handler on the server side?